# How to write proper mathematical sign with Mathjax

Tags: mathjax

*// I first put this question stackoverflow, but was suggested to place the question here as more appropriate*

I would like to write **P[theta | X]** in mathematical notation with `MathJax`. So I used below notation -

```
$$ {P\left[\theta\|X\right]}\propto $$
```

With this the `given` sign i.e. `|` and `proportional to` sign are too small. Attached in the snapshot on my output.

[image]

Any suggestion how to make them properly visible will be highly helpful. I am using Google' `PT-sans` as my font family.

Comment: mathjax-specific questions are off topic here but you could ask the same of latex. you should not use `\left \right` here so `P[\theta\mid X]` should be fine. If you do want a  | that grows with `\left\right` use `\middle|`

Comment: Thanks. P[\theta\mid X] works fine. Can you also suggest how to me the proportional sign more visible and bigger?

Comment: Mathhjax uses an entirely different composition mechanism than (La)TeX.  And unfortunately, that is why Mathjax is off topic here, so we can't help.

Comment: as I show below the prop ought to be bigger. The mathjax font setup is definitely off topic here, but the font you show looks like a serif font to me it's not PT-Sans (but that isn't  a math  font0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need `\left\right` here. The LaTeX markup would be

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[P[\theta\mid X] \propto {} \]

\end{document}
```